# International rules for a king how many moves can the king take if there are no opposition pieces to jump?

Tags: house-rules, checkers

We started to place international rules and just watch a video on youtube that seems to indicate, that a king cannot move unlimited spaces if there are no opposition pieces to jump. Is this correct?

Second question, Is my assumption correct in as much that once a king has jumped one or more pieces in one direction, that after jumping the last opposition piece the king can be moved beyond the last jump piece to any square beyond that will allow the king to take another direction if there is an opposition piece that can be jumped. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Are you saying a king can jump over a piece and land any distance beyond it?

Answer (score 1):

In international rules, the King can move any distance along a diagonal. This holds true whether jumping over a piece or not.

A king is still subject to the rule that it must make a jump if it can, and it must make as many jumps as it can.

So after jumping over a piece, you can choose how far beyond that piece to land. But if one of the spaces beyond the captured piece would allow the king to turn and capture another piece, it must choose to do that.

[image: Example]

I would not think of it as the king moving along the diagonal after a jump; but rather as the jump landing on any square beyond the captured piece.

Reference: https://www.itsyourturn.com/t_helptopic2130.html#helpitem1330

Comment: Then, it there are no possibilities for a jump for your king  - you can move the king as many places as you wish in one direction - correct?  That is you are not limited to move the king without a jump only 1 place ?

Comment: @Duck Correct, that is what my first paragraph is saying.

Comment: Gendolkari.  Thank you for the reconfirmation!  May I ask you the Country and City you are living in ?  Me, I am currently living in Nice, France.  Have a great day.  Bon weekend!! The Duck